# Object detection in captured webcam video stucks after two minutes?

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management, object-detection

I work on a method that detect an object from my webcam (which is already color filtered) with OpenCV. It already works fine, but after two minutes the fps rate decreases for some reason.

Some facts:

- OS: Windows 8.1
- OpenCV: 2.4.10
- IDE: Visual Studio 2013

I think it has something to do with the memory allocation, because as I said it works fine for the first two minutes.

In order to find out if it is computer related, I already tested it on another pc, but there also the same error occurs.

```
void findAndDrawRect(Mat* imgThreshold, Mat* imgOriginal, SerialPort^ arduino){

// contains rectangles - each rectangle exists of points- of imgThreshold 
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;

// contains hierarchical information from black-n white image
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

cv::findContours(*imgThreshold,
    contours,
    hierarchy,
    CV_RETR_TREE,
    CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
    cv::Point(0, 0));

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());

// holds place for rectangle of each contour on the image
cv::Rect boundRect;

// tempory variable to identify largest rectangle
double refArea = 0;
double area = 0;

// pointer to largest rectangle
cv::Rect* obj = NULL;

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    // approximates a polygonal curve for each contour of third grade
    cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);

    // converts polynom of thrid grade to a rectangle
    boundRect = cv::boundingRect(cv::Mat(contours_poly[i]));

    // calculation of the area
    area = boundRect.width * boundRect.height;

    // if area is less than MIN_OBJECT_AREA, the rectangle is probably a noise
    // if area is larger than MAX_OBJECT_AREA, size of rectangle is larger than 2/3 of screen = filter fail or approching cyclist is too near
    if (area > MIN_OBJECT_AREA && area<MAX_OBJECT_AREA && area>refArea){
        refArea = area;
        obj = &boundRect;
    }
}

// if rectangle exists, estimate the distance to the object and send warnings to the helmet
if (obj != NULL){

    //calculation of distance to object
    double currentDistance = (objRealWidth * focal_length) / obj->width;

    // focal length = current measured width of A4 Paper in pixel * distance to camera(measured) / real width of A4 (measured)
    focal_length = (measuredPixelWidth * distanceToCam) / objRealWidth;

    // printf("width: %d \n", obj->width);

    // convert from cm to m
    currentDistance /= 100;

    sprintf_s(Distance, "Distance :%f m", currentDistance);
    putText(*imgOriginal, Distance, Point(0, 50), 1, 1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    rectangle(*imgOriginal, obj->tl(), obj->br(), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0);

    switch (modus){
        case 0: // NOISE
            arduino->WriteLine("1");
            objDetected = '1';
            break;
        case 1: // VIBRATION
            arduino->WriteLine("2");
            objDetected = '2';
            break;
        case 2: // LED
            arduino->WriteLine("3");
            objDetected = '3';
            break;
        case 3:
            //measurement without alerting subject
            arduino->WriteLine("4");
            objDetected = '4'; 
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
else{
    // no object recognized 
    arduino->WriteLine("0");
    objDetected = '0';
}
```

}

After this part of my function, I just draw a rectangle over the picture, which is referenced by the variable obj in the last line of the code snippet.
**EDIT**: The global variable 'objDetected' is used for communication via named pipes:

```
for (;;){
        // This call blocks until a client process reads all the data
        //const wchar_t *data = L"*** Hello Pipe ONUR ***";
        char *data = &objDetected;
        DWORD numBytesWritten = 0;
        result = WriteFile(
            pipe, // handle to our outbound pipe
            data, // data to send
            1, // length of data to send (bytes) + terminating !
            &numBytesWritten, // will store actual amount of data sent
            NULL // not using overlapped IO
            );
```

I really don't know how to remove this problem, since I tried everything I could think of. E.g.: I removed all unused vector entries during calculation, but it doesn't help, so I removed it from the code)

If there any questions feel free to ask and thank you in advance!

Greetings,
a frustrated OpenCV Newbie!

Comment: Just to start, don't use pointers to Mat or Rect. Mat objects are already ref-counted internally.

Comment: is this the full function? why you have `SerialPort^ arduino` parameter? It isn't used there. Please add the rest of the function, including the drawing part...

Comment: Okay I add the rest of the Code, I need the "arduino" parameter to sent messages to the arduino-board. @Micka .

Comment: so " I just draw a rectangle over the picture" wasn't everything... `objDetected` is a global variable? What are you doing with that value outside of the function?

Comment: I used 'objDetected' to communicate with a another program via "named pipes". I think it is not relevant, because i removed the part with "named pipes" and error occurs again.
I added the part where 'objDetected' is used. @Micka

Comment: please remove all pointers to mat objects, as suggested by Miki. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631947/memory-leak-with-mat-in-convertto-function for the reason.

Comment: I already changed it but it doesn't works... :( @Micka

Comment: cv::Rect* obj = NULL; could be the reason for memeory leak.. You need to delete it once you are done with the function

Comment: I implement the remove code obj by writing: delete obj; but the same error occurs @ssh99

Comment: Then I suspect issue is with respect to conversion between IplImage and Mat structure

Comment: I solved the problem! The error occurs because i sent too much a message to the arduino board and after two minutes the "memory" of the arduino board is full and it takes time to handle this messages.